# How to update ReactJS component based on URL / path with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I update a ReactJS component based on URL / path when using React-Router?

The code below works, but is this the correct way to do this? Seems like a lot of code to make a simple update. I was hoping there would be a stateful API call in the router to automatically take care of this scenario.

```
var MyHomeView = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount: function() {
        this.props.updateHeader(); 
   },

   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
         </div>
      );
  } 
}); 


var MyAboutView = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount: function() {
        this.props.updateHeader(); 
   },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="my-page-text">
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var MyHeader = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ CurrentPath ],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
       myPath: "about",
       classes: "ion-ios7-information"
    };
  },   

   updateHeader: function() {    
      // Classnames refer to www.ionicons.com
     if (this.getCurrentPath() === "/") {
        this.setState( {myPath: "about" } );
        this.setState( {classes: "ion-ios7-information" } );
     } else {
        this.setState( {myPath: "/" } );
        this.setState( {classes: "ion-ios7-rewind" } );
     }      
   }, 

  render: function() {
    return (
       <Link to={this.state.myPath}>
          <i className={this.state.classes} />
       </Link>
    );
  }
});


var App = React.createClass({
   updateHeader: function() {
      this.refs.header.updateHeader();
   },

   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <MyHeader ref="header" />

         <this.props.activeRouteHandler updateHeader={this.updateHeader} />
         </div>
      );
  } 
}); 


React.renderComponent((
  <Routes> 
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
      <DefaultRoute handler={MyHomeView} />
      <Route name="about" handler={MyAboutView} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
), document.body);
```

Comment: Why do you keep 'myPath' and 'classes' in state ? Since you have the "getCurrentPath()", could you simply compute the link and className values inside the render function ? Or is "getCurrentPath" not refreshed properly in your case ?

Comment: I'll have to test this out, if `getCurrentPath()` is statefull then it should work without me keeping extra state in `myPath`. I should of tried this as per example in the comments of this file: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/mixins/CurrentPath.js

Answer (score 9):

In react-router 2.0.0 you can use the hashHistory or [browserHistory](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/964):

```
browserHistory.listen(function(ev) {
  console.log('listen', ev.pathname);
});

<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answer all the morning. Now, where would be the best place to put it? main app component?

Comment: I'm glad that this code help you! But I don't understand your question.

Comment: @yarden.refaeli if you use Flux, I think you should add a single listener to your main app, that updates the state of a Store. Then each component can decide to listen to that store and define their own handlers for the changes.

Answer (score 6):

This has been updated if you are working with the react-router > v11.0.

You can read [the details here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc4/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#currentpath---state)

TLDR:

```
 // v0.11.x
 var Something = React.createClass({
   mixins: [ Router.State ],
   render: function () {
      var path = this.getPath();
   }
 });
```

For the full `State` API: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/doc/04%20Mixins/State.md

Comment: This has been changed in react-router v1.0. See: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#state-mixin

Comment: Link `the details here` is dead... You should never link to `master` as it changes all the time. Instead pick the `tag` that corresponds with the current release and use that link.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been open awhile, and it seems like there should be a more straightforward solution, but I'll take a stab and share what we do in our application.

We are using the Flux architecture, which has the notion of Stores that inform components when their state is updated.  In `react-router`, they have a `PathStore` that fits into this model nicely, since when the URL changes it can then notify components that care and need to be updated.

The `StoreListener` we use in our application is publicly available here: https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-flux-suppprt.  I should've published to NPM, but haven't yet.  I'll do that soon if you think it would be helpful.

Here is how we use our `StoreListener` to listen for changes on the `PathStore` from `react-router`, and how you would use it in your `MyHeader`:

```
var StoreListener = require('path/to/StoreListener');
var PathStore = require ('react-router/modules/stores/PathStore');

var MyHeader = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    StoreListener(PathStore)
  ],

  getStateFromStores: function() {
    return {
        path: PathStore.getCurrentPath()
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    var path = this.state.path;
    var myPath;
    var classes;

    if (this.state.path === "/") {
      myPath = 'about';
      classes = 'ion-ios7-information';
    } else {
      myPath = '/';
      classes = 'ion-ios7-rewind';
    } 

    return (
      <Link to={myPath}>
        <i className={classes} />
      </Link>
    );
  }
});
```

This starts with a `mixin` that says "I care about changes to the PathStore".  Whenever this store (or any store being listened to) changes, `getStateFromStores()` is called on your component in order to retrieve the data out of the store that you want available on `this.state`.  If/When that data changes, `render()` is called again, and you re-read `this.state`, and apply your changes.

This is exactly our pattern for applying certain "active" CSS classes on header tabs, or anywhere else in the application that depends on the current URL.

Note that we use [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to bundle our CommonJS modules, so there may be some assumptions about the environment that may/may not work for you.

I didn't answer this question a month ago when I first saw it because I assumed there was a better way, but perhaps our solution can help others with the same issue.

Comment: Nice answer, I'll have to try this out, as I've never used Flux. I was also toying with holding the path's state in <App> but don't see any way to setState() in the <App> component without passing props to children like I already am.

Comment: Can you summarize what you add to Flux in this repo, and why the base Flux isn't enough: https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-flux-suppprt

Comment: By "base flux", do you mean [this repo](https://github.com/facebook/flux)?  If so, that is exactly the code I was augmenting with the code in my repo.  Basically, `StoreListener` gives you a convenient method (`getStateFromStores`) to access the data from your stores and set it on `this.state`.  It binds and unbinds via `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, and calls `getStateFromStores` whenever anything changes.  Thus you have much less boilerplate to write.  The `BaseStore` is simply all the boilerplate you would write in each of your Stores.  Just extend it for convenience.