# How to pass props (both states and functions) to the child router component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Please bear with me. I just learning Reactjs and stuck at a point.

app-client.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={APP}>
            <IndexRoute component={Audience}/>
            <Route path="speaker" component={Speaker}/>
            <Route path="board" component={Board}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

APP.js

```
var APP = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            status: 'disconnected',
            title: ''
        }
    },

  emit(eventName, payload) {
        this.socket.emit(eventName, payload);
    },

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
        );
  }
});
```

Audience.js:

```
var Audience = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<h1>Audience: {this.props.title}</h1>);
    }
});
```

The page is showing all the components, but `this.props.title` is not showing in the page, and the `emit()` is not firing. How do I pass the props to `{this.props.children}` (i.e., Audience or Speaker) on the APP?

**update**:

APP.js render():

```
render() {
    const _this = this;
    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
            { React.children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
                    //Get props of child
                   // const childProps = child.props;

                   //do whatever else you need, create some new props, change existing ones
                   //store them in variables

                   return React.cloneElement(child, {
                       // ...childProps, //these are the old props if you don't want them changed
                       // ...someNewProps,
                       // someOldPropOverwritten, //overwrite some old the old props
                       ..._this.state,
                       emit: _this.emit
                   });
                })
            }
        </div>
        );
  }

});
```

Comment: Use `React.children.map(this.props.children...` with uppercase `Children`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a combination of APIs that React provides you with that will take care of exactly what you're not certain about of how to achieve ( `way to pass props to components rendered by this.props.children` )

First, you need to take a look at [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement)

It will basically take a React element, clone it, and return another with props that you can change, alter or replace entirely based on your needs.

Furthermore, combine it with the [Children Utilities](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) - loop through the children that were provided to your top level component and make the necessary changes to each element individually.

You can find a more comprehensive answer that I provided on a very similar topic for a question that was asked recently below:

[changing-components-based-on-url-with-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006462/changing-components-based-on-url-with-react-router/)

Basically, something along the lines of:

```
render() {
  const _this = this;
  return (
    {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
       //Get props of child
       const childProps = child.props;

       //do whatever else you need, create some new props, change existing ones
       //store them in variables

       return React.cloneElement(child, {
           ...childProps, //these are the old props if you don't want them changed
           ...someNewProps,
           someOldPropOverwritten, //overwrite some old the old props
           ..._this.state,
           someFn: _this.someFn,
           ...
       });
     )}
}
```

Comment: Suppose, I am passing all the states `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.state } )}`. This does pass all the props, but if I had to pass function prop to the child, how would I do that?

Comment: If you had a function defined already somewhere, just pass the reference: `propFn: fnReference .. `

Comment: This `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.state, emit: this.emit } )}` gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.

Comment: You first need to map the children. You clone one child and return that inside your map, not the whole lot. Let me update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Yes please. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Comment: @Robin uppercase on the `Children`.

Comment: Yes, making the `Children` to uppercase did the work. I have accepted your answer as it was the right one. But if you have some time, could you please clear some of my doubts, I really want to learn. 1) Why use of `_this` and not `this`. 2) What are `...childProps`, `...someNewProps` and `someOldPropOverwritten`?

Comment: `_this` because `this` will already be defined inside the block you would be wanting to use it. Unfortunately it wouldn't point to where you'd expect it, hence, saving a reference to the component's `this` as `_this` so it is accessible from anywhere. `...childProps` are you simply taken from the original child and passed along to the cloned element, so you don't lose any of the props along the way. `...someNewProps` is a variable that you could potentially define and make it hold some properties, which you can spread so you don't have to manually define each. `someOld..` to overwrite.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much for your time. This really helped me understand more.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate parent element using Api [React.children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) and clone each element using React.cloneElement

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return (<div onClick={() =>  this.props.doSomething(this.props.value)}>Click Me</div>);
  }
});


var Audience = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return (<div>{this.props.title}</div>);
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({

  doSomething: function(value) {
    console.log('child with value:', value);
  },

  render: function() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { title: "test", doSomething: this.doSomething }));
    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <Child value="2"/>
    <Audience/>
  </App>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ysq2281h/

Comment: Suppose, I am passing all the states `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.state } )}`. This does pass all the props, but if I had to pass `function` as prop to the child, how would I do that?

Comment: Please check, i have updated the example.You can just pass props function to children with the same pattern